# What replacement algorithm does this ALTER TABLE use

Tags: mysql, performance, locking

##### Question

I am trying to figure out what kind of replacement algorithm a command like the following would use

```sql
ALTER TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_store1` COMMENT='Catalog Category Product Index Store1'
```

I am thinking that it would be `INPLACE` as the documentation at  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-performance says

> ALTER TABLE operations that support the INPLACE algorithm include:
>
> ...
>
> An example of such a change is a change to the column comment.

However, that is for a column comment not a table comment and I wonder if that may be different? Can anyone help me figure out what algorithm is used for this statement or if there's a way to log it or something?

Thanks

##### Additional context

The table definition

```sql
mysql> show create table catalog_category_product_index_store1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: catalog_category_product_index_store1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_store1` (
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Category Id',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product Id',
  `position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Position',
  `is_parent` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is Parent',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `visibility` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Visibility',
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`product_id`,`store_id`),
  KEY `CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_STORE1_PRD_ID_STORE_ID_CTGR_ID_VISIBILITY` (`product_id`,`store_id`,`category_id`,`visibility`),
  KEY `IDX_216E521C8AD125E066D2B0BAB4A08412` (`store_id`,`category_id`,`visibility`,`is_parent`,`position`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Category Product Index Store1 Replica'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I believe this query is causing some kind of lock which causes downtime on our site, but I'm not 100% sure on that. I'm trying to understand a little more about what replacement this alter table statement is actually doing and how it achieves it.

Comment: Since `ALTER` without an explicit `ALGORITHM` uses the fastest available, I would not not include the `ALGORITHM` clause.  However, adding it is handy in that it lets you know if the requested algorithm is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL supports metadata comments on the table, columns, indexes, and partitions. In all cases, modifying the comments is a metadata-only action, and it can be done without doing a table copy.

However, any ALTER TABLE, even an inplace alter, requires a [metadata lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/metadata-locking.html). The acquisition of a metadata lock is blocked while any transaction exists that has touched that table.

I can do a demo using two windows:

Window 1:

```
mysql> create table mytable (id int primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
```

Window 2:

```
mysql> start transaction;

mysql> select * from mytable;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

So far so good, that's what we expect. But note that even though that query is done, the transaction is still uncommitted. Therefore the session in window 2 holds the metadata lock on that table.

Window 1:

```
mysql> alter table mytable comment='my table';
<hangs>
```

This is blocked, waiting for the outstanding transaction in window 2 to finish.

Furthermore, any other subsequent query can't get its own metadata lock while window 1 is waiting.

Window 3:

```
mysql> select * from mytable;
<hangs>
```

It's queued up behind the metadata lock request in Window 1.

If I commit in window 2:

```
mysql> commit;
```

Then finally the alter table finishes:

```
mysql> alter table mytable comment='my table';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (4 min 23.98 sec)
```

And then the query in third window also finishes:

```
mysql> select * from mytable;
Empty set (4 min 8.32 sec)
```

In this way, even an ALTER TABLE that does an inplace alter can accidentally cause an outage.

Comment: My take-away is "keep transactions fast".  That is, the alter-comment was an accessory to the crime, not the main guilty party.